# An error occurred while processing your request. MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a MVC 4 application, I had error like following.

[image]

I tried lot of things but I can't find what is the problem.here is my Controller source

```
    public ActionResult Index(string EventId)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            string Type = (cookie["Type"] == null || cookie["Type"] == "") ? null : cookie["Type"].ToString();
            string Username = (cookie["Username"] == null || cookie["Username"] == "") ? null : cookie["Username"].ToString();
            ViewBag.Message = Type;
            ViewBag.Username = Username;


            try
            {
                string ReplaceEventID = EventId.Replace('-', '/');

                ViewBag.Message = ReplaceEventID;
                IEnumerable<Job> JobListRelatedToEvent = DBContext.Jobs.Where(x => x.EventId == ReplaceEventID);
                return View(JobListRelatedToEvent);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
When it run on my local machine it works fine, but after i published to the server I got this error.

Can anyone tell about what's the wrong?

Comment: I don't have much experience with MVC, but aren't you redirecting to the same Action, thus getting in a loop?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your action method? If not debug it and if you are getting any exception, post it here.

Comment: I forgot to mention something I'll update.

Comment: in my local machine it works fine, but after i published to the server then this error occurred.

Comment: I suggest you retrieve and paste server event log here. There is no clue whats going wrong

Comment: I would be suspicious of a race condition. My guess would be that DBContext is a Connection already closed exception. This is occuring because you context is closed before the list is enumerated. Between these two lines.

IEnumerable<Job> JobListRelatedToEvent = DBContext.Jobs.Where(x => x.EventId == ReplaceEventID);
return View(JobListRelatedToEvent);

comment out your return View(); and above it add throw; 

<customErrors mode="Off" />

That should expose the exception to browser so you can take a step forward.

Answer (score 25):

I am facing the same issue and this issue we are getting if the custom error is on.

What you need to do the changes in web.config and add the below code. 
So, you will get the actual error of the application or in code level.

```html
<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Now insted of generic page of IIS it will shows the error.

Comment: This was really helpful to see the actual error on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but I ran into an issue where the POST action had [RequireHttps], but the GET didn't. That caused the issue for me. So, check you don't have restrictions on one verb and not the other, especially with a form post.

The issue didn't show until I published to Production because DEBUG directives removed the [RequireHttps] attribute :)

Answer (score -4):

TRY THIS :

```
 public ActionResult Job(string EventId)
        {

            HttpCookie cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"];

            if (cookie != null)
            {
                string Type = (cookie["Type"] == null || cookie["Type"] == "") ? null : cookie["Type"].ToString();
                string Username = (cookie["Username"] == null || cookie["Username"] == "") ? null : cookie["Username"].ToString();
                ViewBag.Message = Type;
                ViewBag.Username = Username;


                try
                {
                    string ReplaceEventID = EventId.Replace('-', '/');

                    ViewBag.Message = ReplaceEventID;
                    IEnumerable<Job> JobListRelatedToEvent = DBContext.Jobs.Where(x => x.EventId == ReplaceEventID);
                    return View(JobListRelatedToEvent);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
  }
```

Comment: Why? State what the problem is when posting an answer don't just post a block of code. Also, the only difference I can see is you have added a `return View();` statement at a point where the code is unreachable.

Comment: Please explain what your answer is doing.